# Mod_wsgi - configuration failed

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi using with apache2 but i cant:

I placed the mod_wsgi.so file in C:\Apache24\modules directory

In httpd conf file

1) when i try to `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` and restart apache then apache cannot be started - I get an error "The requested operation has failed"

2) when i remove the previous line and add `"WSGIScriptAlias /myapp C:/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi" i get the same error`

Comment: Where did you get the mod_wsgi.so from. Have you made absolutely certain that you used the right one and satisfied all the prerequisites as to what Microsoft compiler version and architecture is used for all the bits. Read https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Comment: I have python 3.4 + apache 2.4 (vc10 ) i download from your link mod_wsgi-py34-VC10.so and placed it in apache's moules directory (rename its name to mod_wsgi.so) -and it sill doesnt work... when i add "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so" to conf file then i cannot start my apache i get "The requested operation has failed" and apache is stoped... please help me

Comment: But do you have 64 bit versions of everything, or conversely 32 bit versions of everything? When you installed Python, did you install it for all users and not just yourself? Are you using the Apache distribution linked to in that link, or a different one?

Comment: I have 64 bit versions of everything, I installed python for all users, i inastalled apache from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC10/..... what else can i do?

Comment: Where is the error "The requested operation has failed" actually appearing? The Apache error log? Edit your question and add the full error message including any lines immediately before and after from the Apache error log. If you claim removing ``LoadModule`` causes the same error, it would suggest there is something broken with the Apache installation to start with as the error should be completely different for the latter.

Comment: the error came when i start the apache(apache monitor) when i  change the conf file i stop the apache and try to start it again and then get the error) when i removed this line the apache can be started again, when i add "WSGIScriptAlias /myapp C:/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi" i get the same error when try to start the apache(from apache monitor) no error in the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82837/discussion-between-lagz-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: If you want to discuss further, use the mod_wsgi mailing list. You still didn't explain where you are seeing the error. Are you looking in the Apache error log file?

Answer (score 0):

reinstalled python for all users and this resolved itself, I must have installed python on windows for "just me" before